# Why can't I run my program with more than 4 GB of memory on 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am creating programs in 32-bit Delphi. My computer runs 64-bit Windows 7 with 8 GB of memory.

When my 32-bit program needs more than 3.8–4 GB memory in Windows 7, it says "Out of Memory".

Is that my program's fault or Windows'?

Comment: If your program takes up almost 4 GB of RAM then it's very likely that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: go get XE2, which is 64-bit        http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41599

Comment: Because it's a 32-bit program.

Answer (score 11):

If your program is written as a 32-bit application, it can only use the 32-bit Windows Subsystem which is still in all versions of 64-bit Windows. To use more than 4GB (or 3GB) you need to recompile your program and target the 64-bit platform.

Answer (score 3):

Your application is still a 32-bit application, so it can only address the maximum of 2<sup>32</sup>=4GB of memory. If you haven't done any configuration, the most likely amount of memory available for your application is only 2GB. Have you considered rewriting your application so that it doesn't need to use so much memory?

Comment: 32-bit processes can only access 2GB of RAM without [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

32-bit programs use 32-bit addresses, hence they **can't address more than 4GB of memory** (unless you use [AWE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/address-windowing-extensions), which can increase the range of memory you can access, but you're still limited to 4GB **at a time**)

However by default you can only use **2GB of RAM** in a 32-bit applications because the higher 2GB is reserved for kernel. You can increase the limit to [3GB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/01/423817.aspx) (4GB in 64-bit Windows) by linking the program with [`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) option and booting with `/3GB` flag. If you see your program really consumes nearly 4GB of RAM then the flag is already enabled, and you can't go beyond that limit

It's also possible that the algorithm you're using is not efficient. Depending on the problem there may be different solutions like [sparse arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4306/995714), dynamic programming, or dividing into small parts and doing only one part at a time... It's impossible to answer without the code. If possible you should ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Either way, the fault lies in your project source code or project settings, and going 64-bit is a better solution. Simple recompile your program as 64-bit instead

Comment: Is there any reason for the down vote? What's wrong with this?